# Relational algebra expression for queries

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

How do I make these expressions of relational algebra?

> These are the tables contained inside a bus driver database.
>
> ```
> • driver( driver_id, driver_name, age, rating);
> • bus( bus_id, bus_name, color);
> • reserves( driver_id, bus_id, date);
> ```
>
> 1. Find the colors of bus reserved by Mark.
> 2. Find all IDs of drivers who have a rating of at least 7 or have reserved bus 112.
> 3. Find the names of drivers who have not reserved a yellow bus.
> 4. Find the IDs of drivers with age over 35 who have not reserved a blue bus.
>
> Using the basic operators.

Comment: people will ask you for some effort first, otherwise they may feel offended by your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my final code. I've searched all over the net but Relational Algebra is pretty tough subject so I just made the first problem only. Do the rest by researching. Goodluck!
I got the (⋈) symbol from Wikipedia. It is called Natural Join.
The other symbols used here are the Greek alphabets pi and delta.
The pi is for the column names. You know if it the column names (attributes) if it is after the SELECT clause.
The delta is for the condition. You know if it the condition if it is after the WHERE clause.
The ⋈ is for the table names. You know if it the table names (relations) if it is after the FROM and JOIN clauses.

```
1)
SELECT b.COLOR
FROM RESERVES r
NATURAL JOIN BUS b
NATURAL JOIN DRIVER d
WHERE d.DRIVER_NAME='Mark';

Relation = ∏COLOR σDRIVER_NAME='Mark' (RESERVES ⋈ BUS ⋈ DRIVER)

2)
SELECT d.DRIVER_ID
FROM DRIVER d
LEFT JOIN RESERVES r
ON r.DRIVER_ID=d.DRIVER_ID
WHERE d.RATING>=7
OR r.BUS_ID=112;

3)
--Long Method
SELECT d.DRIVER_NAME
FROM DRIVER d
WHERE d.DRIVER_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT r.DRIVER_ID
    FROM BUS b
    JOIN RESERVES r
    ON r.BUS_ID=b.BUS_ID
    WHERE b.COLOR='yellow'
);

--Short Method, use this
SELECT d.DRIVER_NAME
FROM DRIVER d
WHERE NOT EXIST (
    SELECT r.DRIVER_ID
    FROM BUS b
    JOIN RESERVES r
    ON r.BUS_ID=b.BUS_ID
    WHERE b.COLOR='yellow'
    AND r.DRIVER_ID=d.DRIVER_ID
);

4)
--Long Method
SELECT d.DRIVER_ID
FROM DRIVER d
WHERE d.AGE>35
AND d.DRIVER_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT r.DRIVER_ID
    FROM BUS b
    JOIN RESERVES r
    ON r.BUS_ID=b.BUS_ID
    WHERE b.COLOR='blue'
);

--Short Method, use this
SELECT d.DRIVER_ID
FROM DRIVER d
WHERE d.AGE>35
AND NOT EXIST (
    SELECT r.DRIVER_ID
    FROM BUS b
    JOIN RESERVES r
    ON r.BUS_ID=b.BUS_ID
    WHERE b.COLOR='blue'
    AND r.DRIVER_ID=d.DRIVER_ID
);
```

Comment: So quick - but I think your last two queries are incorrect.  If the driver has reserved two buses, one blue and one yellow, they will show up in both of your last two queries.

Comment: No see: "Find the names of drivers who have not reserved a yellow bus." But if one driver, 'Bob' for example, has reserved a blue bus and a yellow bus, they will still be returned in your query, even though they have reserved a yellow bus.

Comment: @ChinaPlums The other answer seems right. Use that.

Comment: @marionjeff  are you familiars with these basic operators and to apply it in your answer. [Basic Operators in Relational Algebra](http://mivuletech.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/an-overview-of-relational-algebra-operators-and-their-sql-translations/)

Comment: @marionjeff hello, can i translate these answers to relational algebra operators like select: 
project: 
union: 
set difference: – 
Cartesian product: x
rename: 

Comment: @ChinaPlums Yes you can. Search a reliable source like [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra). Converting SQL into Relation Algebra representation takes a lot of effort. Goodluck for Googling.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to write these queries, but here are some options.

(1) You need to join across the three tables and filter by the name:

```
select b.color
from bus b
join reserves r
on b.bus_id = r.bus_id join
join driver d
on d.driver_id = r.driver_id
where d.driver_name = 'Mark'
```

(alternatively could include d.driver_name = 'Mark' in the join)

(2) you need to do a left join across two tables and filter by the bus_id and rating:

```
select d.driver_id
from driver d
left join reserves r
on d.driver_id = r.driver_id
where r.bus_id = 112
or d.rating >= 7
```

(alternatively could union two queries)

(3) You need to get the drivers that are not in the join:

```
select d.driver_name
from driver d
where not exists (
    select 1 from reserves r
    join bus b
    on r.bus_id = b.bus_id
    where b.color = 'yellow'
    and r.driver_id = d.driver_id )
```

(4) Similar to the last one:

```
select d.driver_id
from driver d
where d.age > 35
and not exists (
    select 1 from reserves r
    join bus b
    on r.bus_id = b.bus_id
    where b.color = 'blue'
    and r.driver_id = d.driver_id )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Understand that im still learning to it so the purpose of getting the answers is my baseline to get correct ideas. Besides i need to translate the answers you've given to relational algebra expression using symbols.

Comment: hello, can i translate these answers to relational algebra operators like select: 
project: 
union: 
set difference: – 
Cartesian product: x
rename: 